# Can I use Stored procedure instead trigger in following case?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I've table with columns
 `studentId`,
 `studentName`,
  `markOne`,
`markTwo`,
`total`.

I created a trigger to calculate `total` by adding `markOne` and `markTwo`..
whenever I update any one of the mark it automatically updates the `total` field.

**ASK:**
But this process can be achieved using Stored Procedure also then why we go for trigger instead Stored Procedure ?

Comment: Trigger invokes automatically when any updates happened.But in case of stored procedure we should call manually.this maybe one of the reason .

Comment: In general I would only use triggers when you have no other choice, or for auditing purposes.  The answer provided by Gordon is the best way to go in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you use either a stored procedure or trigger?  The best solution is to use a computed column:

```
alter table t add total as (markOne + markTwo);
```

This will calculate the value correctly whenever you refer to `total`.

Note:  You'll need to remove the table from the table or re-create the table without the actual column.

Answer (score 0):

In your condition, you don't require a trigger.You want to only update total field, so don't use triggers.

Trigger use in such a condition, when you add data for markone, marktwo, then it affects many tables.In more than 2-3 table, you need to update the database on two fields.Then you can use triggers.In your case you can simply use stored procedures.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view for this, so you dont have to alter your table.

```
create view vwMyTable as
  select studentId, 
         studentName,
         markOne,
         markTwo,
         (markOne + markTwo) as Total
  from   myTable
```

Then you can simply do

```
select * from vwMyTable
```